# How to use colemak keyboard layout in Dosbox?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, dosbox, colemak

I configured Windows to use the Colemak keyboard layout. This works fine in all apps—except Dosbox, which reverts to Qwerty.

How can I get Dosbox to respect the keyboard layout I chose in Windows and use Colemak?

Comment: Read the documentation [Keyboard Layout](http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#KeyboardLayout)

Comment: Ideally you'd just type `keyb co` as in FreeDOS http://superuser.com/a/982117/62691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download https://gist.github.com/gonejack/0655029de3465cb78f3e and install it to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\DOSBox`