# How to use Colemak keyboard layout in Freedos?

Tags: freedos, colemak

I installed Freedos onto a usb stick (using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/))

Out the box it uses the qwerty keyboard layout. How can I make it use the Colemak keyboard layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I make it use the Colemak keyboard layout?

Run the command:

```
keyb co
```

---

#### KPDOS v3.0 - Keyboard Layout Pack for DOS codepages

> KPDOS contains library files to be used with KEYB.  The official
>   FreeDOS tool to make one of the files below to work with   one of its
>   possible codepages is MODE.
>
> To use MODE, DISPLAY must already be running.
>
> All the CPI files in this list are the ones available at the CPIDOS
>   package. The source files can be compiled by KC, which in turn can be 
>   included into customized library files by KLIB.
>
> More details available on the KC package, which also includes KLIB.
>
> **FreeDOS official keyboard layouts, v3.0**
>
> This is the list of all the names of the keyboard layouts available
>   for   FreeDOS. When the name is in the format zz999, it means that
>   there is a   name AND an identifier which MUST be specified otherwise
>   KEYB will load   the layout of another keyboard for that country.
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   Layouts available on the KEYBOARD.SYS library file
>   ==================================================
>
>   Country/Region                   Name    Codepages                CPX
>   --------------                   ----    ---------                ---
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    (Colemak)                       co      858, 850, 437            EGA
> ```

Source http://home.mnet-online.de/willybilly/fdhelp-dos/en/hhstndrd/base/kpdos.htm

Comment: I don't understand. Do I need to download something? What do I type?

Comment: Read the source link. You need to use `keyb co` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Easiest keyboard layout switching ever.